# Android alarm not working using AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alertdialog

I have a android project that I have been working on. I wrote a another android project that I wrote to test alarms alone. I ant to the alarm project to my main project, however now this is not working, I don't get any alarms at all.

The code of the working alarm project is:
AlertDemo.java
    package com.example.servicealarmdemo2;

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AlertDemo extends DialogFragment  {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is displayed */
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
        builder.setTitle("Alarm");
        /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
        builder.setMessage("An Alarm by AlarmManager");
        /** Defining an OK button event listener */
        builder.setPositiveButton("Take", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                /** Exit application on click OK */
                getActivity().finish();
            }                       
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Snooze",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        //  @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)  {
                 EditText text=MainActivity.text;
                 Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");               
                 PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                 long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
                 String str = text.getText().toString();                 
                 long t=Long.parseLong(str);
                 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                         time+( t*60*1000), operation);
            }
        });
        /** Creating the alert dialog window */
        return builder.create();
    }
    /** The application should be exit, if the user presses the back button */ 
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

DemoActivity.java
    package com.example.servicealarmdemo2;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        /** Creating an Alert Dialog Window */
        AlertDemo alert = new AlertDemo();
        /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window */
        alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "AlertDemo");
        Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        mVibrator.vibrate(300);
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(DemoActivity.this, R.raw.beep);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

and MainActivity.java:
    package com.example.servicealarmdemo2;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static EditText text;
    @Override
    public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickListener setClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox box1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                CheckBox box2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);       
                CheckBox box3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);       
                CheckBox box4=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);       
                CheckBox box5=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);       
                CheckBox box6=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);       
                CheckBox box7=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);       

                /** Getting a reference to TimePicker object available in the MainActivity */
                TimePicker tpTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_time);
                int hour = tpTime.getCurrentHour();
                int minute = tpTime.getCurrentMinute();

                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                int month;
                int day;
                int year;

                Date date =new Date();
                c.setTime(date);

                if(box1.isChecked()) {
                    /** This intent invokes the activity DemoActivity, which in turn opens the AlertDialog window */
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");
                    /** Creating a Pending Intent */
                    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    c.setTime(date);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY);


                    month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                    /** Getting a reference to the System Service ALARM_SERVICE */
                    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                   /** Creating a calendar object corresponding to the date and time set by the user */
                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);

                    /** Converting the date and time in to milliseconds elapsed since epoch */
                    long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                    /** Setting an alarm, which invokes the operation at alart_time */
                    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
                    alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,7*24*3600*1000, operation);
                }

                if(box2.isChecked()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");
                    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    c.setTime(date);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.TUESDAY);

                    month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);                  
                    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);
                    long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
                    alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,7*24*3600*1000, operation);

                }

                if(box3.isChecked()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");
                    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    c.setTime(date);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.WEDNESDAY);

                    month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);                  
                    AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);
                    long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    alarmManager3.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
                    alarmManager3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,7*24*3600*1000, operation);
                }

                if(box4.isChecked()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");
                    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    c.setTime(date);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.THURSDAY);

                    month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);                  
                    AlarmManager alarmManager4 = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);
                    long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    alarmManager4.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
                    alarmManager4.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,7*24*3600*1000, operation);
                }

                if(box5.isChecked()) {
                     Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");
                     PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                     c.setTime(date);
                     c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);

                     month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                     day=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                     year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);                 
                     AlarmManager alarmManager5 = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                     GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);
                     long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                     alarmManager5.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
                     alarmManager5.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,7*24*3600*1000, operation);
                    }

                if(box6.isChecked()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");
                    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    c.setTime(date);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SATURDAY);

                    month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);                  
                    AlarmManager alarmManager6 = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);
                    long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                    alarmManager6.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
                    alarmManager6.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,7*24*3600*1000, operation);
                }

                if(box7.isChecked()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.servicealarmdemo2.demoactivity");
                    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    c.setTime(date);
                    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);

                    month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);                  
                    AlarmManager alarmManager7 = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);
                    long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    alarmManager7.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
                    alarmManager7.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,7*24*3600*1000, operation);

                }


                /** Alert is set successfully */
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
                 text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


            }
        };      

        OnClickListener quitClickListener = new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        };

        Button btnSetAlarm = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_set_alarm);
        btnSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(setClickListener);

        Button btnQuitAlarm = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_quit_alarm);
        btnQuitAlarm.setOnClickListener(quitClickListener);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to use the same project with my main project, mainly the alarm functionality.
The code for my main project.

Alert.java:
    package com.example.appzheimerbeta4.widgets.alerts;

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

public class Alert extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Alarm");
        builder.setMessage("An alarm by AlarmManager");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Take", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //TODO decrement pills here
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Snooze", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AlertActivity.class.getPackage().getName() + ".alertactivity");
                PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                final long snoozeTime = 2; // 2 mins
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + (snoozeTime * 60 * 1000);

                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, operation);
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

AlertAcitivty.java:
    package com.example.appzheimerbeta4.widgets.alerts;

```
import com.example.appzheimerbeta4.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class AlertActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Alert alert = new Alert();
        alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Alert Demo");

        Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vib.vibrate(300);

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(AlertActivity.this, R.raw.beep);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java
    package com.example.appzheimerbeta4;

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import com.example.appzheimerbeta4.widgets.alerts.AlertActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String patientID = "Patient1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.caregiverBtn); // using the caregiverBtn as a test subject to test for alerts
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int hour = 22;
                int minute = 11;

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int month;
                int day;
                int year;

                Date date = new Date();
                c.setTime(date);

                Intent i = new Intent(AlertActivity.class.getPackage().getName() + ".alertactivity");
                PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                c.setTime(date);
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);

                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute);

                long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, operation);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please if anybody could help me figure out this problem. I have been working on it for the past couple days and I couldn't find any way to fix it.

NOTE: If I need to provide other pieces of code, please tell me so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an `Intent` like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlertActivity.class.getPackage().getName() + ".alertactivity");
```

you are using the `Intent` constructor that takes an ACTION string. This creates a new `Intent` and sets the ACTION field in the `Intent` to this string. This is used to create an **implicit** `Intent` and will only start your activity if you have configured an `<intent-filter>` in the manifest for your alert activity. You haven't posted your manifest, but I'm guessing you haven't done that.

If you want to start your alert activity, just create the `Intent` like this instead:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlertActivity.class);
```

This uses the `Intent` constructor that sets the component in the `Intent` **explicitly**.